# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisClientPool' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, junit, redis

I write a program to practice redis.But when i run as a JUnit Test,there are problems:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisClientPool' defined in class path resource [spring/applicationContext-redis.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jedisPool' of bean class [cn.e3mall.common.jedis.JedisClientPool]: Bean property 'jedisPool' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at cn.e3mall.jedis.JedisClientTest.testJedisClient(JedisClientTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jedisPool' of bean class [cn.e3mall.common.jedis.JedisClientPool]: Bean property 'jedisPool' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:231)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    ... 36 more
```

Here is my [test:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIvEU.png)

Here is [applicationContext-redis.xml:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PSmh.png)

**JedisClientPool.java:**

```
package cn.e3mall.common.jedis;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;

public class JedisClientPool implements JedisClient {

    @Autowired
    private JedisPool jedisPool;

    @Override
    public String set(String key, String value) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        String result = jedis.set(key, value);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        String result = jedis.get(key);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean exists(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Boolean result = jedis.exists(key);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Long expire(String key, int seconds) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Long result = jedis.expire(key, seconds);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Long ttl(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Long result = jedis.ttl(key);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Long incr(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Long result = jedis.incr(key);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Long hset(String key, String field, String value) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Long result = jedis.hset(key, field, value);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String hget(String key, String field) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        String result = jedis.hget(key, field);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Long hdel(String key, String... field) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Long result = jedis.hdel(key, field);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean hexists(String key, String field) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Boolean result = jedis.hexists(key, field);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> hvals(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        List<String> result = jedis.hvals(key);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Long del(String key) {
        Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
        Long result = jedis.del(key);
        jedis.close();
        return result;
    }

}
```

**JedisClient.java:**

```
package cn.e3mall.common.jedis;

import java.util.List;

public interface JedisClient {

    String set(String key, String value);
    String get(String key);
    Boolean exists(String key);
    Long expire(String key, int seconds);
    Long ttl(String key);
    Long incr(String key);
    Long hset(String key, String field, String value);
    String hget(String key, String field);
    Long hdel(String key, String... field);
    Boolean hexists(String key,String field);
    List<String> hvals(String key);
    Long del(String key);
}
```

could you help me?thanks!!

Comment: I don't see getters/setters of `JedisClient` instance in `JedisClientPool`

Comment: Yes.Problem solved.Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see getters/setters of `JedisClient` instance in `JedisClientPool`.

Do create them.